# How do workflows in TidyModels apply recipe steps to CV folds?

Tags: tidymodels

To control for a minority positive class for the project I'm working on, I'm implementing `step_downsample()` in my recipe. I'm also using 10-fold cross-validation to mitigate bias. When I use a workflow to wrap up the learner, recipe, a grid search, and the CV folds, does the workflow apply the recipe steps to each individual fold prior to model training? The order of operations is hazy to me and I wasn't able to find any satisfactory answers in the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might find [this chapter](https://www.tmwr.org/workflows.html) helpful, especially the section ["Where does the model begin and end?"](https://www.tmwr.org/workflows.html#begin-model-end).

**Yes**, in tidymodels, the preprocessing recipe (i.e. feature engineering procedure) is considered part of the modeling process and is trained on each fold like the learner.

You can see this happening in the logging if you set `verbose = TRUE` during tuning:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(themis)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'themis'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:recipes':
#> 
#>     step_downsample, step_upsample
data(Ionosphere, package = "mlbench")

svm_mod <-
  svm_rbf(cost = tune(), rbf_sigma = tune()) %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("kernlab")

iono_rec <-
  recipe(Class ~ ., data = Ionosphere)  %>%
  # remove any zero variance predictors
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  # remove any linear combinations
  step_lincomb(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_downsample(Class)

set.seed(123)
iono_rs <- bootstraps(Ionosphere, times = 5)

set.seed(325)
svm_mod %>% 
  tune_grid(
    iono_rec,
    resamples = iono_rs,
    control = control_grid(verbose = TRUE)
  )
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> i Bootstrap1: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> i Bootstrap2: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> i Bootstrap3: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> i Bootstrap4: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/10 (predictions)
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> ✓ Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10
#> i Bootstrap5: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/10 (predictions)
#> # Tuning results
#> # Bootstrap sampling 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   splits            id         .metrics          .notes          
#>   <list>            <chr>      <list>            <list>          
#> 1 <split [351/136]> Bootstrap1 <tibble [20 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 2 <split [351/124]> Bootstrap2 <tibble [20 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 3 <split [351/134]> Bootstrap3 <tibble [20 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 4 <split [351/130]> Bootstrap4 <tibble [20 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 5 <split [351/138]> Bootstrap5 <tibble [20 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

In this particular case, it walks through each resample and first trains the recipe, then fits the first learner/parameter option, then evaluates predictions on the heldout set for that resample and learner/parameter option, then goes to the next learner option.